# Global.asax Application_start fired on every action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, lucene.net

I am working on a MVC project and the performance was fine.

On application_start the database gets indexed for the lucene.net search (and on every change on an object the index is extended). But application_start runs on every action I call on the page.

Why is it firing application_start not only once? I will post any code when I know where to look ;)

I'm not sure if the web.config may cause this behaviour...

Solution:
Lucene.net wrote its index to the bin folder, after changing the path the application is not melting my face anymore :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be because when Lucene builds its index it modifies some of the files (web.config, global.asax, bin folder, etc...) that would cause AppDomain to unload.

Comment: In web.config there is nothing about lucene, but in the bin folder there is a folder named _indexes... maybe this is from lucene? The guy who set up lucene is gone (external programmer) and not available in the next two weeks.

Comment: If the bin folder is modified the application will restart. You need to reconfigure Lucene to store its index elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the web.config gets modified somehow.
To track it down try to set Read-Only attribute of the web.config and see if there are any errors.

Really the main place to look at is the web.config, possibly in sobfolders too.

Comment: after the application started I set the web.config and the bin folder + subfolders to readonly and still application_start is called :(